# How to redirect to login page when session out using fosuserbundle?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm using fosuserbundle for login page in symfony 3. I'm studying their documentation ([link](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)) and follow their instructions. I have already a login form. It work fine when login, but there is no sample here that will limit the session timeout and then will redirect to login page if session is out. I don't know if there are configuration that need to work this, I don't want to use the native PHP session like this one

```
session_start();
```

It will be glad if you have tutorials that will guide me on how to work in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the lifetime in your configuration, like in the [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html)

Comment: I try to use cookie_lifetime and I set it to 3 mins. I'm trying test if does it work. I click everything in my page and when the time I reach 3 mins. I log out the page. I suppose not to logout because I'm still active in doing the page. does cookie_lifetime work that way? read your doc and find sample for it that the same issue of mine. they use the cookie_lifetime

Comment: that was'nt your question , post another question for this problem. this is a very different question, i think you can't do this natively